# Non-computable numbers and surreals

Tags: computability, number-systems, surreal-numbers

Can non computable numbers be expressed with surreal numbers?
Show the construction using Conway's definition of surreal.

Comment: The surreals contain all the reals, also the uncomputable numbers. Why would they be missing?

Comment: What you mean by "non-computable number"? As in, a real number that is not an element of the computable reals (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_reals)?

Comment: There are gaps in the surreal number system, but they are not the non-computable reals. See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456068/a-question-about-something-in-conways-on-numbers-and-games

Comment: Show the construction using Conway's definition of surreal.

Comment: It is considered impolite on this site to phrase questions as orders ("show the construction ...").

Comment: SUCCJNCT REPRESENTATION, 
RANDOM STRINGS, AND COMPLEXITY CLASSES • 
file:///C:/Users/ge/Downloads/tr69.pdf

Comment: @11dim I think you were trying to link to [Peterson's paper](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/fileDownloadForInstitutionalItem.action?itemId=10310&itemFileId=22681) but accidentally linked to a file on your computer. In any case, it's not clear to me why you were linking it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be expressed as $\{A \vert B\}$ where $A = \{x: x \lt \Omega\}$ and $B = \{x: x \gt \Omega\}$ and $\Omega$ is [Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

Comment: Wouldn't that definition just give omega?

Comment: Wouldn't that definition just give omega? Since a uncomputable number's digits are totally random and the only way to generate its digits is with a pure random number generator, I have difficulty seeing how to generate uncomputables with the surreal number definition. I do not have a problem with other surreal numbers.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not sets if $x$ ranges over the surreals, so that $\{A|B\}$ is undefined. However, you can restrict $x$ to, say, the dyadic rationals, and then you are correct. Also, @11dim should keep in mind that this answer is sort of vacuous; the surreals don't have magical power to express a non-computable number in any special way that couldn't be done with reals.

Comment: @11dim More importantly, in your comment, you said "a uncomputable number's digits are totally random and the only way to generate its digits is with a pure random number generator" which is very far from the truth, and if you are not sure why I suggest reading up on computable numbers a bit more and then perhaps asking separate questions about them here on math.SE.

Comment: I should have said "one way" instead of "the only way". I do know that Chaitin's number is a uncomputable number.

Comment: SUCCJNCT REPRESENTATION, RANDOM STRINGS, AND COMPLEXITY CLASSES • file:///C:/Users/ge/Downloads/tr69.pdf